# update php application using app fog

Tags: php, git, ssl, rubygems, appfog

I have an account on App fog, I have depolyed the app on it using `af update app-name` but my php code creates some file on the server the server, Now I want to download the updated code from the server, 
I tried using `af pull app-name` and also `af push app-name` but both didn't worked form me
Anyone who can guide me 
2-Is there any free hosting provider that can provide free ssl hosting?

Comment: see https://heroku.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An af pull won't bring back any files that have been created on the server, only the files that were last pushed or updated to the server.
The file system of appfog instances is non-persistent, so on restart or update any files will be deleted.
If you are creating anything you need to keep then I'd recommend storing them to a AWS S3 bucket.